# Super collider and black hole

Tags: black-holes, wormholes, particle-accelerators

I've read somewhere that to create a wormhole we would have to build a supercollider on the side of the solar system. If we were capable of doing this, would a supercollider of this scale create its own black hole when turned on due to the energy and the gravitational force it would be exerting?

Comment: This question is a bit non-specific: where did you read it, and was there even a proper argument for why it is needed? One can construct solar-system-wide colliders in many ways, and some almost certainly do not collapse.

Answer (score 2):

Even if wormholes are possible, it is unlikely that the supercollider would collapse into a black hole, because the collider would probably be creating a very small wormhole with a much higher density than the density of the collider. More specifically, this depends on the size of the collider and the amount of energy stored in it. In the simplest case of the Schwarzschild's black hole, the gravitational radius (the radius of the event horizon) is given by

$$ R=\dfrac{2GM}{c^2} $$

Where the total stored energy of the collider (including its mass) is

$$ E=Mc^2 $$

Combining the formulas gives you the total stored energy that would make a collider of the radius $R$ a black hole

$$ E=\dfrac{Rc^4}{2G} $$

Where $G$ is the gravitational constant and $c$ is the speed of light. If the collider is about 3 km in radius, it would have to store the energy equivalent to the mass of the Sun to become a black hole.

Answer (score 2):

General relativity essentially forbids topology change. (For a more technically careful statement of this, google on "topology change." Basically it can't happen without causality violations or exotic forms of matter, which we don't think exist.) That means that if GR is correct, no amount of energy is enough to create a wormhole that didn't already exist.

Comment: Yes, however if we're talking about particle collisions affecting spacetime geometry, this is a scale at which quantum mechanics is important and that means we effectively have to be dealing in quantum gravity. This would be expected to change the rules of general relativity considerably. Whether it admits for topology change is, as with virtually any other question about it, entirely conjectural as of now given we have no evidence to support one proposed version of a quantum theory of gravity over any other, or over something else entirely we've never even thought of yet.

Comment: Naively, one can imagine that if one would be able to assign a quantum amplitude to different possible geometries, there could (depending on what the theory allows) arise a state in which a nonzero amplitude appears for a geometry with a different topology. This "reconciles" the discontinuous nature of topology changes with continuous evolution in the same way that quantized energy levels of an atom are reconciled with continuous evolution, or for tunneling or other classically-forbidden transitions.

Comment: or tldr - "if GR is correct" is a big claim under these parameters.